# Algorithm - Find groups of connected tiles

Tags: arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I'm terribly sorry for the title, but describing my problem with a couple of words is a tad hard. I figured the rest of the post would explain it better! ;)

**Description**

I basically have a 2D array of tiles/objects/symbols and I want to split it up into two (or more) new 2D arrays whenever a group of tiles is separated by special tiles.

For example, if I have:

**[x][x]**[0][0]

[0][0]**[x]**[0]

[0][0]**[x]**[0]

[0][0][0]**[x]**

Where the symbol x is not wanted, then that should give me two new arrays:

**[x][x]**[0][0]

**[x][x][x]**[0]

**[x][x][x]**[0]

**[x][x][x][x]**

and

**[x][x][x][x]**

[0][0]**[x][x]**

[0][0]**[x][x]**

[0][0][0]**[x]**

One array for each group of interconnecting tiles.

In my specific case, I have null objects as x, and an arbitrary object for the rest. Basically, if I can't reach tile B from tile A without crossing a null, then those two are two different groups.

I've played with it in my mind for a while, and the best I could come up with is surely far worse than O(n^2), given that they even worked in the first place. [Flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) springs to mind as something that could be used to find a group, but other than that, I'm not sure I can come up with any other similar problem to use in this instance.

**The question**

So what I'm asking is if you happen to know in which direction to take my problem and/or how to solve it. Computational complexity is not that very important since I plan not to execute this often nor on large arrays. Still, I hope i haven't hit upon a NP-hard problem! :3

Thanks!

Comment: "union find" could be a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I hope i haven't hit upon a NP-hard problem!

This is far from being a NP problem.

I will explain two different approaches to solve the problem. One will use a [Flood Fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) as you expected and the other a [Disjoint-set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) data structure.

### Flood Fill

Let's say you have a matrix `N x M` where a position `(row, column)` is `null` when is not used, it contains a value otherwise.

You need to go through each column element `1..M` per row `1..N`. That's very simple:

```
for row in range(1, N + 1):
  for column in range(1, M + 1):
    if matrix[row][column] is not null:
      floodfill(matrix, row, column)
```

You will need to call the Flood Fill algorithm each time you find a non-`null` value, the reason will become clearer after I will define the Flood Fill method below.

```
def floodfill(matrix, row, column):
  # I will use a queue to keep record of the positions we are gonna traverse.
  # Each element in the queue is a coordinate position (row,column) of an element
  # of the matrix.
  Q = Queue()

  # A container for the up, down, left and right directions.
  dirs = { (-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1) }

  # Now we will add our initial position to the queue.
  Q.push( (row, column) )

  # And we will mark the element as null. You will definitely need to
  # use a boolean matrix to mark visited elements. In this case I will simply
  # mark them as null.
  matrix[row][column] = null

  # Go through each element in the queue, while there are still elements to visit.
  while Q is not empty:

    # Pop the next element to visit from the queue.
    # Remember this is a (row, column) position.
    (r, c) = Q.pop()

    # Add the element to the output region.
    region.add( (r, c) )

    # Check for non-visited position adjacent to this (r,c) position.
    # These are:
    #   (r + 1, c): down
    #   (r - 1, c): up
    #   (r, c - 1): left
    #   (r, c + 1): right
    for (dr, dc) in dirs:

      # Check if this adjacent position is not null and keep it between
      # the matrix size.
      if matrix[r + dr][c + dc] is not null
         and r + dr <= rows(matrix)
         and c + dc <= colums(matrix):

        # Then add the position to the queue to be visited later
        Q.push(r + dr, c + dc)

        # And mark this position as visited.
        matrix[r + dr][c + dc] = null

  # When there are no more positions to visit. You can return the
  # region visited.
  return region
```

You can modify this algorithm to mark each region with an specified number in a different array if you keep track of the number of regions recognized. You will notice I am using a queue instead of a recursive function, this will keep you away from hitting a maximum recursion bound limit.

### Union-Find Algorithm

Another solution that I considered more expensive is using a Disjoint-set data structure to accomplish the same purpose. I will merely show the change to the `floodfill` method.

```
def floodfill(matrix):
  disjoint_set = DisjointSet()

  # Go through each row in the matrix
  for row in range(1, N + 1):

    # Go through each column in the matrix
    for column in range(1, M + 1):

      # Create a set for the current position
      disjoint_set.makeSet(row, column)

      if matrix[row - 1][column] is not null:
        # If the position north of it it is not null then merge them
        disjoint_set.merge((row, column), (row - 1, column))

      if matrix[row][column - 1] is not null:
        # If the position left of it it is not null then merge them
        disjoint_set.merge((row, column), (row, column - 1))

  # You can go through each position identifying its set and do something with it
  for row in range(1, N + 1):
    for column in range(1, M + 1):
      regions[ disjoint_set.find(row, column) ] = (row, column)

  return regions
```

I hope this help.

I didn't bother about showing the complexity since you didn't care about it.

Comment: Floodfill is the way to go, O(n) and very easy to implement

Comment: You mean `O(n^2)`. Well, `O(n*m)` in my explanation.

Comment: Yeah well, O(n) where n is the number of cells

Answer (score 3):

It seems you need [connected-component labeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) algorithm to produce separated groups of objects